# title is shown only after page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, popupwindow, hashtag

My website has following url. I want to change webpage title when user visits this link http://localhost:8080/krishi/#modal2 (Actually it is popup window). So I've used following code.

```
if(window.location.hash === "#modal2"){
    document.title = "Modal2";
    }
```

I tried using code inside

```
1. $(document).ready(function(){})
2. window.onload=function(){}
```

Title is changed in first click and if I refresh url only. I think it is because of cache, So I also add following code to refresh url so it refresh current page once and title is shown.

```
if(window.location.hash === "#modal2"){
    window.location.reload();
    document.title = "Modal2";
}
```

but it not works. It is looped. Please suggest any idea to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just call your modal on click function and in that code also add the code to change the title

Comment: Thanks @Ashishsah, simply the best answer. I had tried many way, but can't work properly. But on click function works properly.

Comment: you can mark out my ans so that it may help others thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use a `hashchange` event. Here is a demo of firing this event at  *[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hyqen7e5/1/)*:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  alert('window.location.hash = ' + window.location.hash);

  if(window.location.hash === "#modal2"){
    document.title = "Modal2";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use on click events to solve your query. It will be easy and a better way to that. Try changing your code by click events, It will be a better and simpler way. Thanks.